# Including Microsoft.XNA.Framework.Input.Touch in a project?

Tags: xna, c#, xna-4.0, microsoft

So after running through tutorials by both Microsoft and [www.xnadevelopment.com](http://www.xnadevelopment.com) I feel very confident in my ability to get to work on my first game using the XNA Framework. I've manipulated sprites, added audio, changed game states, and even went a step further to apply the knowledge I had and figure out how to make animations and basic 2-dimensional physics (including impulses, force, acceleration, and speed calculations)

But then shortly into the project I hit a curious bump that I've been unable to figure out.

In wanting to implement menus, pause screens, and several different aspects of play (a "pre-level" prep screen, the level itself, and a screen after the level to review how well you did) I took a look at Microsoft's [Game State Management sample](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management). I understood the concept, although it was admittedly quite a lot to take in. Not wanting to recreate the entire concept by scratch (after all- what purpose would that serve?) I tried copying and pasting the sample code into my own `ScreenManager` class (as well as `InputState` and `GameScreen` classes) to try and borrow their ingenuity. When I did this, however, my project stopped compiling. I was getting the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'Touch' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Having read through their sample code already, I realized that this namespace and every function and class within it could be safely ripped from the code without losing functionality. It's a namespace simply for integrating with touchscreen devices (presumably Windows Phone 7, but maybe also tablets).

But then I began to wonder- how come Microsoft's sample compiled but mine didn't? I copied their code exactly so there must be a setting somewhere that I need to change in Visual Studio in order to correct this. I tried creating a new project as a Windows Phone 7 game rather than a Windows game, however that only forced it to compile to a Windows Phone emulator and denied me the ability to change the resolution and other features which I clearly had the power to do in the sample code.

So my question is simple - how do I properly use the namespace Microsoft.XNA.Framework.Input.Touch?

Comment: Did you download the right version for your expected use, that is, Windows/Xbox or Windows Phone? I noticed that there was two separate samples of the tutorials respectively. I just compiled using VS2010 and I had not to remove or modify any of the namespaces.

Comment: I did download the "WIN XBOX" version, however if you'll look at `ScreenManager.cs` then you'll notice at the top it has the line `using Microsoft.XNA.Framework.Input.Touch`. Even though it's not intended for use on Windows Phone 7, it still has support for touchscreen gestures (possibly for tablets running Windows 7?)

Comment: +1 Interesting, I imported the ScreenManager classes and the Screens classes to my test game project, and I encounter the same as mentioned in your question. Working on it now! =)

Comment: Had you tried to add the reference to within your project? After having added the `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch` reference to my project, it compiled fine.

Comment: Add the reference? Do you mean via `#include`ing, or is that a project setting within Visual Studio? Not sure about that term o.o Googling it now (edited - including -> include)

Comment: From within Visual Studio, right-click on your project and then **`Add|Reference`**, click the .NET tab if it isn't active, then select the `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch` assembly, it will correct no longer annoy you with the error about "missing reference".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Input.Touch is only available in WinPhone7 projects. You can't use it on Win7. I don't know why the XNA team decided to do this. In the beta, Input.Touch worked on Win7 just fine.

Comment: Shawn Hargreaves explains it here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/09/09/touch-input-on-windows-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx

Comment: +1 for mentionning this. @Andre Russel: Pretty mice article you got there! Thanks for sharing! =)

Comment: Good point to mention, and I assume this means all the functions and classes within Input.Touch are now meaningless after compiling, but that doesn't change the fact that adding a reference did make it compile (my original question). For now accepted, but I'd like to see it mentioned that adding a reference makes it compile.

Comment: @Andrew Russell : Thanks for digging that up. I know I'd seen it somewhere. It makes my own experience seem even more strange, though.